# ¿Qué significa estos requerimientos en Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Me solicitan que el **web service** que estoy desarrollando debe tener lo siguiente:
¿A qué se refiere, qué debo hacer?

> El servicio deberá cumplir con la especificación WS-Security que
>   incluye, entre otros:
>
> - Manejo de Timestamp (estampas de tiempo) para validez del mensaje usando el TAG estándar wsu:Timestamp
> - Manejo de firma digital del mensaje SOAP en el encabezado (Header) usando el TAG estándar wsse:Security apoyado en certificados
>     digitales.
> - Manejo de encripción del contenido del mensaje SOAP (Envelope) usando el TAG estándar xenc:EncryptedData
> - Comunicación mediante canal seguro HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bien,
El servicio debe:

- **Manejo de Timestamp (estampas de tiempo) para validez del mensaje usando el TAG estándar wsu:Timestamp**
  Vas a tener que usar las funciones de Timestamp para que el mensaje sea valido por un periodo de tiempo, por ej: 1 hora.
- **Manejo de firma digital del mensaje SOAP en el encabezado (Header) usando el TAG estándar wsse:Security apoyado en certificados digitales.**
  El canal se autentica con certificados.
- **Manejo de encripción del contenido del mensaje SOAP (Envelope) usando el TAG estándar xenc:EncryptedData**
  El contenido que aparece dentro del tag  debe estar encriptado.
- **Comunicación mediante canal seguro HTTPS.**
  Debera estar segurizado (puerto 443), tendrá la forma *https://ip.de.tu.servicio/NombreServicio*

---

Este es un ejemplo inventado de como quedaria un mensaje SOAP:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Header>
            <wsu:Timestamp 
                xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility">
                <wsu:Created>2002-11-07T21:51:51Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2002-11-07T21:56:51Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" 
                xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
                <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="wsse:X509v3" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" 
                    xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-547309ee-532f-40ce-a370-a64be85e977e">MIIHRjC ... HVUjaoy                        
                </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                <Signature 
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <SignedInfo>
                        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                        <Reference URI="#Id:ce249a29-aa9a-427a-b0c4-830cdc7f481a">
                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                            <DigestValue>7yhtDGpxNtkFGT9+1vWHI7sQL1c=</DigestValue>
                        </Reference>
                    </SignedInfo>
                    <SignatureValue>tNj18ILnxAyc/3AoNCRb+ZBcYcIp5KCKTFLCTNhAzuokk5m1S8FOBvFYTUdy1qCU2i655/KCcIzZ7lzLSqY57iaoWgdpQBAWvEEhxkSNuGGl/qoknNhc4B2SN24t1AniB4UwNFvo2u6rHiBr3nSfAv0rSPuGa32c3Ri8LRcqZ5M=                </SignatureValue>
                    <KeyInfo>
                        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-547309ee-532f-40ce-a370-a64be85e977e" />
                        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </KeyInfo>
                </Signature>
                <xenc:EncryptedKey 
                    xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
                    <ds:KeyInfo 
                        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <wsse:KeyIdentifier>FHejk...  </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                    <xenc:CipherData>
                        <xenc:CipherValue>d2FpbmdvbGRfE0lm4byV0... </xenc:CipherValue>
                    </xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:ReferenceList>
                        <xenc:DataReference URI="#enc1"/>
                    </xenc:ReferenceList>
                </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            </wsse:Security>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <xenc:EncryptedData 
                xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" 
                xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" wsu:Id="enc1">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#3des-cbc"/>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>d2FpbmdvbGRfE0lm4byV0...                      </xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedData>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Lamentablemente no hay muchas referencias en español pero te dejo estos dos links en ingles:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996951.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951253.aspx

Comment: Muchas gracias compadre, aun no me queda muy claro pero como tu dijiste... la información respecto a este tema es muy pobre y casi no encuentro nada, pero algo me ayudó ver el mensaje de ejemplo.